# "Unknown stepping info, firmware loading failed"

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, 16.10, i915

During boot up of Ubuntu 16.10, my Acer Aspire F5 (Intel i5-7200u) has a firmware loading error. 16.04 had the same problem.

It looks like it first tried to load i915_bpo 2.0, which fails, and then it successfully loads i915_bpo 1.6, which succeeds but may be causing downstream problems (this laptop has been suffering some random freezes that I've reported in another thread).

So, how do I overcome this difficulty loading this firmware?

var/log/kern.log has this sequence in it:

```
Jan 14 10:43:26 prop6 kernel: [ 1.002400] [drm:parse_csr_fw [i915_bpo]] ERROR* Unknown stepping info, firmware loading failed
Jan 14 10:43:26 prop6 kernel: [ 1.002405] i915_bpo 0000:00:02.0: Failed to load DMC firmware [https://01.org/linuxgraphics/intel-linux-graphics-firmwares], disabling runtime power management.
Jan 14 10:43:26 prop6 kernel: [ 1.006089] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
Jan 14 10:43:26 prop6 kernel: [ 1.018209] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes rom: no post: no)
Jan 14 10:43:26 prop6 kernel: [ 1.018522] input: Video Bus as /devices /LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input5
Jan 14 10:43:26 prop6 kernel: [ 1.018601] [drm] Initialized i915_bpo 1.6.0 20160229 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
```

I can't get any info from its frozen state to see if it might be related to this firmware; even ssh becomes inert, so for now I am pursuing this as a separate problem until I know more.

PS: I'm a user-space programmer, not a very experienced sys admin, and not a kernel developer, so most suggestions will mean my learning new tools (needing references to study).

Finally, if the firmware load failure is an actual bug that can't be fixed manually or worked around, then please help me discover what package to report the bug against. I've already learned that a bug report will be round-filed if it is posted without a known source-code package.

That makes it difficult for user-space folk like me to report deep problems such as processor-specific firmware, but I'll give it a go if I can get some coaching with the investigative techniques.

Comment: I don't know why, but my upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10 left me with an unchanged kernel, the problematic 4.4 from Ubuntu 16.04. According to my recent reading, the stepping info problem and freezing of Intel CPU's (that have embedded HD graphics) is/was an issue through kernel 4.5, fixed in 4.6+. A fresh install of 16.10 gave me kernel 4.8, and it has been stable for days. My take-away lesson is that to solve this problem, get kernel 4.6+. One way is to install a stable 16.10+ version fresh from bootable media (an incremental upgrade might not suffice).